# How to export pandas dataframe to json in specific format

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is

```
  'col1' , 'col2'
    A    ,   89
    A    ,   232
    C    ,   545
    D    ,   998
```

and would like to export as follow :

```
{
  'A' : [ 89, 232 ],
  'C' : [545],
  'D' : [998]   
}
```

However, all the to_json does not fit this format (orient='records', ...).
Is there a way to ouput like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for convert to `list` and then [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_json.html):

```
json = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(list).to_json()
print (json)
{"A":[89,232],"C":[545],"D":[998]}
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(list))
col1
A    [89, 232]
C        [545]
D        [998]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```